# PDF Files Hosted On Dreamhost Not Opening In Chrome

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, dreamhost

I have a site, hosted on Dreamhost, with several pdf files.  When I try to open them in Chrome's pdf viewer, the viewer opens but I get a "Failed To Load PDF Document" message or sometimes the view doesn't open at all and I just get a 503 message.  On another site that I know to be hosted on Dreamhost I get the same issue.  All other content on these sites load fine.

If I use another browser to open with another PDF viewer (Preview or Adobe Reader) the pdfs from my site load fine.

If I try to open pdfs from other sources in Chrome's viewer they work fine.

Is there something I can do on my end to fix this?  Is this something likely caused by Dreamhost?  Has anybody else had an issue like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not recommended by Dreamhost, you can resolve this issue by unchecking the "Extra Web Security?" option under "Manage Domains" in the control panel.  This feature uses Apache's `mod_security` to add request filtering and provide security for your site.

If you still want this feature enabled, you will have to add a .htaccess file in the root of your site to bypass some of the filtering.  To allow access to a specific pdf, you would need add something like

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/example\.pdf$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
</IfModule>
```

Here's [more information](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mod_security) on Dreamhost's use of `mod_security` and writing custom .htaccess rules.

Comment: Sort of weird, but the problem just resolved itself.  Thanks for the Dreamhost info, though.